# mysql access denied in prod

Tags: mysql, symfony

I would like to configure my application on my production server but Symfony can't access to MySQL server.

logs/prod.log:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception PDOException: "SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'login'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

**Symfony doesn't care what I set in my parameters files:**

But I tried to change the MySQL login (to know which config file is used) in `config/parameters.yml` and `config/parameters_prod.yml` and then clear the cache with `app/console cache:clear --env=prod` but the login who appears in the logs/prod.log is not updated...

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony_db
    database_user: login
    database_password: ***
```

How/Where can I manage the MySQL access ?

Note: When I try a `mysql -u login -p` I can access to the MySQL server.

Comment: maybe try with 127.0.0.1

Comment: @SylvainGuilbert but when I update the login in my config files, it's not take into account by symfony, i'm afraid that is the same with the server_name

Comment: sorry did not understand your question well.

Comment: I don't know how manage the symfony mysql access

Comment: Can you update config file also? like config/parameters.yml and config_prod.yml

Comment: @PiyushGupta Yes, but when I updated `config/parameters_prod.yml` and `config/parameters.yml`, clear the cache and reload the page, the mysql login who appears in the log is not the one I have set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to drop the cache of symfony when changes are made in config/parameters_prod.yml.

Try to delete the "cache" folder in you app.

Comment: It works !!, strange that `app/console cache:clear --env=prod` doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

You must create a user who has permissions on your base :

```
create user symfony_user@localhost;
set password for symfony_user@localhost = password('symfony_user_password');
grant all privileges on symfony_db.* to symfony_user@localhost;
```

You can now try to connect to this base with this user :

```
mysql -u symfony_user -p symfony_db
```

Tell me if it helps

Comment: I have already a user who has only access to the Symfony database and it works from ssh

Comment: Wait, the mysql server isn't the same server where Symfony is?

Have you set the db host in your symfony settings?

Comment: I set config/parameters.yml and config/parameters_prod.yml

    parameters:
        database_host: 127.0.0.1
        database_port: null
        database_name: symfony_db
        database_user: login
        database_password: ***

I tried to change the database_user and refresh my page but it's still the old user who appears in the log, so I don't know how manage the mysql access with symfony

Comment: Can you confirm that you can connect to your database using this command :

Comment: mysql -u login@localhost -p symfony_db

Comment: with @localhost no `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'login@localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` but without yes

Comment: that's why i told you to create a user like in my answer :) try it with another account if you don't want to delete the existing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115287/discussion-between-paul-and-r-dussin).